# Use a Categorie from an customIOS Framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, categories

I don't even know if it's possible, I searched but didn't find something like that.

**I made a custom Framework** (with [jverkoey/iOS-Framework](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#walkthrough)) designed to be a collection of other frameworks and tools for every project in my company.

**In this framework I have a simple Categorie** "UIImage+H568" which is simply used to automatically load images for iphone 5 when they exists.

**What I want is that categorie be automatically used in projects that use my framework**, or at least, these project can call the categorie like it was in the project itself.

Thank you for help :)

PS : I don't want to use the category in the framework itself, I have no problem to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

I think the following Technical Q&A of Apple should help

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html

Comment: I realize that I already did it, but in fact, my UIImage was in a xib --' so the framework don't affect it. (It's just a test project to see if the framework work well)
I'm just distracted, but thank for help. I validate because it's the correct answer anyway, just I should have seen my mistake sooner.